# How CoverStory supports XCODE 4.0.1, using LLVM as compiler?

Tags: xcode, coverstory

How does XCode 4.0.1 (LLVM 2.0) + CoverStory (code cover tool provide by google) to produce code cover data?

The following WIKI explains how does CoverStory work with XCODE 3.2 and 4.2, I wonder how to integrate with  XCODE 4.0.1, using LLVM as compiler? *.gcno, *.gcna files aren't produced when follow XCODE 4.2 configuration instructions.

http://code.google.com/p/coverstory/wiki/UsingCoverstory

Any idea or discussion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.